# Flask use marked up db query return as argument?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I hope this is possible.

Is there a way to pass back a returned element from a db query as an argument to a url_for?

It is being marked up by jinja template, but it is not a form element.

```
@app.route('/matcher/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_entries():
    #global account_id
    global load_file_id
    if request.method == 'GET':
        option = str(request.args.get('button'))
        load_file_id = int(request.args.get('a'))
        if option == 'All':
            sql = """SELECT *
                     FROM TABLE WHERE LOAD_FILE_ID = :load_file_id"""
            c = g.db.cursor()
            c.execute(sql, load_file_id=load_file_id)
            rows = c.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1], text1=row[2], text2=row[3], text3=row[4], text4=row[5], text5=row[6], text6=row[7])]
                media = row[8]
                account_id = int(row[0])
                c.execute("""UPDATE TABLE SET STATUS = 'PENDING' WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = :account_id""", account_id=account_id)
                g.db.commit()
                outs = mediapod(account_id)
                return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries, media=media, outs=outs, src=src)
            c.close()
     elif:
           ############DOESN'T MATTER#############
```

and then

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    {% if session.logged_in %}
        {% for entry in entries %}
        <div class=entry>
        <form action="{{ url_for('next') }}" method=get
              class=validate>
            <h2 name=id>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
            <div class=subentry>
                <div class=titles>
                INFO:<br>
                INFO:<br>
                INFO:<br>
                INFO:<br>
                INFO:<br>
                INFO:<br>
                INFO:<br></div>
                <div class=elements>
                ${{ entry.text|string }}<br>
                {{ entry.text1|string }}<br>
                {{entry.text2|string }}<br>
                {{ entry.text3|string }}<br>
                {{ entry.text4|string }}<br>
                {{ entry.text5|string }}<br>
                {{ entry.text6|string }}<br></div>
                <div class=mediatable>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Doc ID</th>
                            <th>Scan Date</th>
                        </tr>
                {% for put in outs %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ put.media_type|safe }}</td>
                            <td>{{ put.statement_date|safe }}</td>
                            <td>{{ put.media_status|safe }}</td>
                            <td>{{ put.doc_id|safe }}</td>
                            <td>{{ put.scan_date|safe }}</td>
                        </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                    </table>
                </div>
            <div class=buttons>
            <input type=radio name=box value=match>Match
            <input type=radio name=box value=nomatch>No Match
            <input type=radio name=box value=fup>Follow-Up
            <input type=radio name=box value=nomedia>No Media
            <input type=submit class=next name=submit value=Next>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        {% else %}
            <em>stuff</em>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

and then I have a route after that that needs to take the account_id from show_entries()

```
#Next Button
@app.route('/next', methods=['GET'])
def next():
    status = request.args.get('box')
    c = g.db.cursor()
    c.execute("""UPDATE TABLE
                 SET STATUS = :status
              WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = :account_id""",
              {"status" : str(status),
               "account_id" : account_id
               })
    g.db.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('nextnext'))
```

Comment: [`url_for` docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#url-building) You can pass arguments to `url_for` for methods that expect an argument.

Comment: I get that, but what do I pass it?  Let's say I set to def next(account_id): then how do I use the element to pass to the url_for('next') ?

Comment: `url_for('next', account_id=100)`

Comment: ok, but I don't know what the account_id is going in.  The query returns it, the template renders it, and I need to pass it back abstractly.

Comment: `return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries, media=media, outs=outs, src=src, account_id=account_id)` in the view and `url_for('next', account_id=account_id)` in the template.

Comment: throws this at me: TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got '='

Comment: Wait, I'm a dip...I had incorrect syntax in where I put the parentheses.  That did the trick.  How do I give you credit?  If you want to post it as an answer I'll check it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a peak back at the [`url_for` docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#url-building):

> It accepts the name of the function as first argument and a number of keyword arguments, each corresponding to the variable part of the URL rule.

`url_for` can be used in your Python source:

```
from flask import url_for

url_for('index')
```

and in your templates:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"></a>
```

If you want your `next` method to receive a value as part of the URL, then you can change the method definition to

```
@app.route('/next/<int:account_id>', methods=['GET'])
def next(account_id):
    # ...
```

then you can pass the variable through the `url_for` call, either from the Python source or from your templates:

```
url_for('next', account_id=account_id)
```

If you need your `show_entries` view to have that value in the template, then pass the value with the `render_template` call:

```
return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries, media=media, outs=outs, src=src, account_id=account_id)
```